# PHP - inserting values error: Check SQL version

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to insert a few values into a database but it doesn't work. It show an error.

> You  have  an  error  in  your  SQL  syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','pranavkumar.chess@gmail.com')' at line 1

I need to do something about it. So, can you help please.

The portion PHP Code is:

```
$reason= $_GET['reason'];      
$option= $_GET['option'];
$for= $_GET['category'];
$approved= $_GET['approved'];
$before= $_GET['before'];
$username= $_SESSION ["username"];
     $myquery="INSERT INTO request (`serial number`, `request date`, `request for category`, `request`, `reason`, `approved by`, `username`) VALUES  ('',NOW(),'$for','$option','$reason',$approved','$username')";
     $query = mysql_query($myquery);

     if ( ! $query ) {
                     echo mysql_error();
                     die;
  }
```

Comment: echo your query and directly into phpmyadmin and looking for error

Comment: Echo your query and then check what you write wrong.

Comment: Your missing a quote before $approved

Comment: missing `'` before `$approved` at `'$reason',$approved',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single Quote missing @ '$approved'

```
     $myquery="INSERT INTO request (`serial number`, `request date`, `request for category`, `request`, `reason`, `approved by`, `username`) VALUES  ('',NOW(),'$for','$option','$reason','$approved','$username')";
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have missed a quote before $approved variable.

Try this one:

```
$reason= $_GET['reason'];      
$option= $_GET['option'];
$for= $_GET['category'];
$approved= $_GET['approved'];
$before= $_GET['before'];
$username= $_SESSION ["username"];
$myquery= "INSERT INTO request (`serial number`, `request date`, `request for category`, `request`, `reason`, `approved by`, `username`) VALUES  ('',NOW(),'$for','$option','$reason','$approved','$username')";
     $query = mysql_query($myquery);

     if ( ! $query ) {
                     echo mysql_error();
                     die;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use PDO:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO request (`serial number`, `request date`, `request for category`, `request`, `reason`, `approved by`, `username`) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute([
    '',
    $for,
    $option,
    $reason,
    $approved,
    $username
]);
```

Second, in:

```
('',NOW(),'$for','$option','$reason',$approved','$username')";
```

Change:

```
',$approved','
```

that is why:

```
','$approved','
```